# Pydantic validation model validate foreign key

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

I have to Sqlalchemy Classes for my FastApi app:

```
class Book(Base):
    id= Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    author_id=Column(ForeingnKey('author.id'))

 class Author(Base):
     id=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
     name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True)
```

when I have to insert/delete/update a book the user is sending me the author name so I have to: make a query that is going to find the author with that name and to substitute it with his author id.

when I have to select a book I need to do the opposite from author_id to author_name (my response needs to contain the name and not the id).
Is there a way to automize this process with pydantic?
Something like this:

```
class Book(BaseModel):
    id: int =Field(return_in_api=False)
    title: str = Field()
    author_name: str = Field() # hey pydantic when you deserialize my sqlalchemy object find the name of the author with the id that I am passing you
```

I am quite sure  flask-sqlalchemy and marshmallow relationships allow you to do that